# Translated Navisworks file - CAD elements are displaced

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

Good Day,

we experience a strange issue with a file from a customer, where some CAD elements are in a wrong place in the translated SVF2.

Here is a screenshot of the original Navisworks file:
[image: Screenshot Navisworks]

Here is a screenshot of a translated file in the Forge Viewer:
[image: Screenshot Forge Viewer]
Note the missing sheet piles.

The sheet piles are located in a completely different location:
[image: Screenshot Displaced Elements]

To check what’s going on, we also uploaded the file to Autodesk Docs.
Here the model looks fine:
[image: Screenshot BIM360]

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Wolfgang

Comment: Could you share a non-confidential reproducible NWD/NWC model to `forge (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com` for investigation?

Comment: Hi, I replied to the Forge Help ticket you raised. Unfortunately, I have no luck to find the displaced elements using your reproducible model.

Comment: I've renamed the file, run the translation process again, and now it looks fine.
But it's a bit worrying that the process doesn't always produce the expected results.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the new good news!

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the file and translating it to svf2 helped resolve this issue.

1. Rename the file
2. Upload it to OSS
3. Request an SVF2 translation like the below

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
   "input": {
     "urn": ""
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf2",
         "views": [
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work reliably.
More often than not, it doesn't work.
What still baffles me - when I upload to BIM 360, it looks fine.

Comment: Also, when I isolate the items in Navisworks, create a saved view, and translate only the visible items, it looks fine too.

Comment: Could you share the reproducible models with Forge Help? Your snapshot in the emails shows another one.